# How to use wp_add_inline_style for custom CSS added via shortcode?

Tags: php, shortcode

I am trying to avoid inline CSS and move the custom CSS to the head of HTML document.

Found this article https://www.cssigniter.com/late-enqueue-inline-css-wordpress/ and tried to implement this solution for shortcode, but have problem to get global variable $custom_css that is set in div_shortcode to my_custom_css function ( value is empty, but should be, for example: .my-div {color: red;} )?

Shortcode usage:

```
[div style="color: red"]Example[/div]
```

PHP Code:

```
$custom_css = '';
function div_shortcode($attr, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array('style' => ''), $attr));
    $output = '<div class="my-div">';
    $output .= do_shortcode($content);
    $output .= '</div>';
    global $custom_css;
    $custom_css = '.my-div {'.$style.'}';
    return $output;
}

function my_custom_css(){
    global $custom_css;
    wp_register_style( 'my-custom-css', false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-css' );
    wp_add_inline_style( 'my-custom-css', $custom_css );
}

add_shortcode('div', 'div_shortcode');
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_css' );
```

The result I want is to get in the head of HTML:

```
<style id='my-custom-css-inline-css' type='text/css'>
.my-div {color: red;}
</style>
```

and in the output of post content:

```
<div class="my-div">Example</div>
```

Comment: Where do you intend to place the shortcode? Shortcodes are typically for the post editor. If you want to inject CSS into the head, you can user the header.php file (although I don't recommend it). You should look at `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Comment: In the example above it is just regular shortcode code for text editor.

Comment: Shortcodes are run inside `the_content` so they are after the head has been output. You would probably be better off to add the CSS to your `style.css` (if using a child theme) or in the Customizer - either of those methods will put your CSS in the `<head>`. Then, have your shortcode just output the class - though it may be just as easy to type in `<div class="red-div">` as it is to type `[div style="color: red']`. Or perhaps I am misunderstanding and you are wanting to add arbitrary CSS rules rather than a set of fixed styles?

Comment: I am developing theme and trying to avoid inline CSS when user is using parameters for changing colors. There seeems to be a solution to render CSS in head based on dynamic shortcode parameters, please have a look here  https://www.cssigniter.com/late-enqueue-inline-css-wordpress/ I am  trying to use this solution, but need help to implement it for shortcode.